# Navigation pane still shows

Tags: windows-10

Expand to open folder is already unchecked, but navigation pane still shows up when I click on a link to a folder on my computer.  I almost never want to see the navigation pane.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation pane shouldn't appear if you've configured it correctly not to show it. **Uncheck** both options - `Navigation Pane` and `Expand to open folders`:

[image]

*(Uncheck both of the highlighted options)*

And this is it. Navigation pane no longer visible :

[image]

I hope this helps :)